# Possessive function of a business name which is made with a possessive

Tags: possessives, proper-nouns

Garner's fourth edition, page 714, states regarding the name *McDonald’s*

> It is quite defensible to write *McDonald’s dinner combos* (the name
>   functioning as a kind of possessive)

On what grounds can  a business name which is made with a possessive function as a (kind of) possessive?

Secondly, is the same true for a business name created with a plural noun, therefore ending in -**s'**? (I am not a native speaker, and unfortunately cannot come up with an example right now)

Comment: whatever looks less cluttered is the way to go. punctuation is a style issue.

Answer (score 2):

If the possessive is a part of the business name, it doesn't make sense to reduplicate the possessive:

> (x) McDonald's's dinner combos
>
> (x) McDonald's' dinner combos
>
> McDonald's dinner combos

Furthermore, eliminating the possessive would misconstrue the name of the business:

> (x) McDonald dinner combos
>
> (x) McDonalds dinner combos

In other words, since the business name already takes the form of a possessive, the default name and the possessive have the same form. Whether it's read as a possessive or as an [attributive](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-attributive-noun-1689012) noun (a noun that modifies another noun), "McDonald's dinner combos" makes sense.

Incidentally, Garner uses these terms (including referring to the *attributive* usage) in a [blog post on the subject](https://abovethelaw.com/career-files/lawprose-lesson-113-how-do-you-form-a-possessive-with-a-name-that-itself-ends-with-a-possessive-s-as-with-mcdonalds/):

> ... the best solution is to rephrase {the french fries at McDonald’s [not McDonald’s’s french fries]} {the closing hours for T.G.I. Friday’s [not T.G.I. Friday’s’s closing hours]}. But it’s also defensible to write **the McDonald’s french fries** (with the name functioning **attributively**)—and perhaps even **McDonald’s french fries** (though this is strictly illogical).

I don't know of any businesses that employ a plural possessive in their name. If they did, however, the answer would be the same: use the form of the name whether it is treated as a noun, an attributive, or a possessive.

Comment: The company was founded by Samuel B. Thomas, so the business name is NOT created with a plural noun. Yet, assuming such a family name of a business, say Xs, the form it'd take is Xs'. Now, how woud the possessive marker be added to it? Or even added to its plural (or similarly the plural of _Thomas'_, which I do not know how to form, so I'd appreciate an explanation too)

Comment: If you can find a company with a plural possessive, let me know.